# Where does Android store disabled packages list?

Tags: adb, root-access, services

So I was playing with `adb pm uninstall` and now my phone doesn't boot.
So I'm actually curious, how really `pm uninstall` works, where does it store the list of uninstalled packages (if it does) and if there is a way to revert the changes I made via `adb shell` with root.

Comment: The is a file named `/data/system/packages.xml` which contains a lot info on each installed app. I never checked it but this would be a good place to start searching.

Comment: Disabled package states are stored in `/data/system/users/<UserId>/package-restrictions.xml`. Uninstalled packages are, well, uninstalled. They aren't disabled.

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted (check mark)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question. No there's no way to  get back an uninstalled app on Android like in Windows where you can restore back to a point in time - that feature unfortunately isn't that well developed in Linux ( Android is a far off modification of Linux ). if you had uninstalled using this ( below ) command instead of `pm uninstall` ( which just hides the app as against throw it out )

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 <package>
```

you could re-install using

```
adb shell cmd package install-existing <package>
```

sounds like you don't quite fit in  the above. In that case your other options are

-hunt around the internet for the same `package` name and see if you can re-install it ( chances are fat to find the same  exact version and esp if its system app it may not install correctly or if it used `crypto keys` ) 
-Backup existing data. If you have an older `/system` backup then restore that after a full wipe.
-Resintall new `ROM`from scratch and restore data from `backup`